# Dynamically map JSON keys to HTML form elements with same key/name

Tags: javascript, html, json

Think of an HTML form with too many dynamically generated inputs and textareas which are identified by their `name` property; now on the other hand there's a large JSON data coming and there are keys in data corresponding to input names.

I'm wondering if there's a way to put JSON values in input's with same key/name without doing a loop on JSON or HTML elements?

Comment: You may map them dynamically, using some data-binding solution, but that would most certainly use a loop somewhere in the implementation. What is wrong with this?

Comment: I'm looking for data-binding solution. Loop might be slow when it come to large count of items.

Comment: Do not try to prematurely optimize, and I don't think that a general data-binding solution will be faster, as it is *general*, hence most likely more complex, than a one-off solution.

Comment: Imagine a panel for users to create complex forms and a large json data that is being loaded on the fly with ajax and json keys should bind to form elements. What's your solution? Don't you think looping on DOM elements to find their data in json is a bad practice?

Comment: Basically you are navigating in two objects, which are already loaded into the memory, so my instinct is telling me, that looping will not be the bottleneck.